# How to stop animation after hoverOut?

Tags: jquery, animation, hover, toggle, slidetoggle

as inpired from this website:
http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery/demo/jquery_demo_slick_jquery_sliding_captions.htm

I have created my own version using the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".transparencyOverlay").css("display", "none");
  $(".thumbnailTextContainer").css("display", "none");

  $(".contestantFirst, .contestant").hover(function(){
    $(this).children(".transparencyOverlay, .thumbnailTextContainer").slideToggle('slow');
  },function(){
    $(this).children(".transparencyOverlay, .thumbnailTextContainer").slideToggle('slow');
  });

});
```

The problem is that when I hover in and out consecutively within the images, the animation will continue to run even when my cursor is outside the images, anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: use `$(this).children(".transparencyOverlay, .thumbnailTextContainer").stop(true).slideToggle('slow');` to stop animation and then begin to slide...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mouseenter to trigger the animation and then mouseout to stop it with [jQuery's stop() function](http://api.jquery.com/stop/). A generic example:

```
$('div').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).slideToggle('slow');
});

$('div').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).stop();
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DeXRT/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the jQuery .stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] ) function

http://api.jquery.com/stop/